# BibLaTeX inline citing: How to get "(author, year)"?

Tags: biblatex, citing

I need some help with BibLaTeX: I want to have the cite (what is inline with the other text) being `(author, year)` and I searched through the net but found no solution. I still want to use the `\printbibliography` at the end of my Document, and only change the inline citation.

Can anyone give me the code needed to perform the inline citation?

Comment: Can you give more information on what you have tried already. If you could include a MWE it would assist members give you an answer. Welcome to Tex.

Comment: Using any `authoryear` style in with `biblatex`, you can use `\parencite{ ... }` for this style *(Author, year)* and `\textcite{ ... }` for *Author (year)*.

Comment: The following might be sufficient to get you going: [The most basic biblatex example](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/141957)

Comment: i just tried \parencite{} and it resulted in (Author year) but without the , inbetween

Comment: @Commentator2.0 Then you need to edit your question with a complete but minimal compilable document that shows exactly what you did. (Not a fragment of code.)

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest that you (a) add the options `natbib=true` and `maxcitenames=1` (or `maxcitenames=2`, which seems to have the same effect) while loading `biblatex` and (b) use the `\citep` macro to generate parenthetic-style citation callouts with a comma between the author group and the year.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{test.bib}
@misc{a:3001, author = "Anne Author", title = "Thoughts", year = 3001}
@misc{ab:3002, author = "Anne Author and Brenda Buthor", 
  title = "Deep Thoughts", year = 2002}
@misc{abc:3003, author = "Anne Author and Brenda Buthor and Carla Cuthor",
  title = "Further Thoughts", year = 3003}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber,
            natbib=true,maxcitenames=1]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}
\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}
\citep{a:3001}, \citep{ab:3002}, \citep{abc:3003}

\citep{a:3001,abc:3003}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: As @moewe has noted in a comment, the same result may be achieved by (a) dropping the option `natbib=true`, (b) adding the directive

```
\DeclareDelimFormat{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
```

after loading `biblatex` and (c) using `\parencite` or `\autocite` to generate the citation call-outs.

Comment: Since the `natbib` option surely has nothing to do with the comma issue, it might be helpful to show the `\parencite` version too. I think of the `natbib` option as a kind of compatibility option for people switching over, rather than one that new users should be pointed to.

Comment: @AlanMunn For historic reasons `biblatex`'s `natbib` mode sets `\DeclareDelimFormat{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}`, so it indeed makes the comma appear. But I agree, I think it would be better to leave the `natbib` option and `\citep` aside and just show `\parencite` (or better `\autocite`) and `\DeclareDelimFormat`.

Comment: @moewe - Many thanks for these very specific and detailed comments. I've posted an addendum to make your suggestions a part of the "official" answer.